# Agreement of noun adjective: Should I use masculine or feminine for the adjetive with this noun?

Tags: traducción, gramática, selección-de-palabras, género

How do you translate "the first Easter Hare" correctly?

Someone (a native) told me:

> La **pimer** liebre de Pascua

but I think it must be:

> La **primera** liebre de Pascua

Since it's a female hare, but i am not sure if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look for ["liebre" in the dictionary](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NHUNgob)

> **liebre**
>
> 1. **f**. Mamífero del orden [...]

That `f` there tells you that it's a feminine noun (if you hover over it it will display "nombre femenino"), so you'll use "primer**a**" and not "primer" with "liebre".

It is a *feminine noun*, which means we use it both for male and female hares

> La liebre macho es más **alta y roja** que la liebre hembra, que suele ser más **pequeña y blanca**.

(this is not actually true, but I just wanted to point out that I used female adjetives in all cases, because the noun is feminine, regardless of the actual gender of the animal)

Notice that, unless some exception cases, you'll say

> El primer X (being X a masculine noun)

or

> La primera Y (being Y a feminine noun)

Adjectives must agree in gender with the noun (except some exception cases).

As [Alvalongo explains in his answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27935/5481), in Spanish speaking countries traditions vary and where they have this reference they might call it the "conejo" and not "liebre". Since "[conejo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ADak4g1)" is a masculine noun we say

> El primer conejo

in this case the dictionary entry is for "*conejo, ja*" which is "nombre masculino **y** femenino" (respectively) so you could say

> La primera coneja

so, just for fun and to compare with the previous example

> El conejo (macho) es más **alto y rojo** que la coneja (hembra), que suele ser más **pequeña y blanca**

Comment: Aside: there's a widespread (and spreading) tendency to elide the final *-a* in feminine ordinals. I've just heard the President of Argentina welcome Donald Trump to the G20 Summit "en su primer visita a Argentina". So it's mistake, but a very common one that often goes unnoticed.

Answer (score 2):

la traducción sería:

```
La primera liebre de Pascua
```

Sin embargo es más común oir que se usa la palabra "conejo", entonces quedaría:

```
El primer conejo de pascua
```