# ¿Por qué es "el mapa" y no "la mapa"?

Tags: etimología, género

¿Hay alguna razón por la cual el género de esta palabra es masculino? Me refiero a históricamente. Hay reglas en el español como la de la A tónica que hacen cambiar el género de la palabra aún cuando pudiera ser femenino; por ejemplo, El águila o El agua. Sin embargo, mapa no entra en los criterios de esta regla como para cambiar a masculino.

Comment: Nota que *águila* es voz femenina.

Comment: Consulta el diccionario: [Mapa](https://dle.rae.es/?w=diccionario) es **masculino** (mira esa "m." al lado del nombre. Si pones el cursor encima explica que es un "nombre masculino"). Por tanto, decimos "**El** mapa nuev**o**" y no "_La_ mapa nuev**a**"). Esta pregunta es muy similar a [Agreement of noun adjective: Should I use masculine or feminine for the adjetive with this noun?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/27934/5481) así que la voy a marcar como duplicada. Si piensas que son suficientemente distintas pon un flag para reabrir.

Comment: @Diego  una pregunta sí interesante sería porque mapa se convirtió en masculino, siendo una palabra latina que originalmente era también femenina, y en todas las lenguas ibéricas lo era también antes de masculinizarse en algún momento en las lenguas occidentales (galaicoportugués, leonés, castellano, y tal vez aragonés) y ahora afecta a medias al catalán (que lo tiene como masculino en singular, femenino en plural)

Comment: @guifa cierto, pero a menos que haya entendido mal la pregunta, (que creo que es porqué no se usa el artículo femenino sino el masculino) esa no es la pregunta que se está haciendo. Si lo es, por favor editad para clarificar. Editad, votad para reabrir, haced una pregunta "spin-off" con la que propones, etc. Lo que veáis oportuno.

Comment: @guifa "mappa" originalmente era femenino y significaba "trapo, servilleta". Estos se usaban para dibujar, y de ahí "mappa mundi", literalmente "el trapo del mundo" o "mapa del mundo". Hay casos de "la mapa del mundo" en textos del siglo XV, pero también "un mapa mundi", por lo que entiendo que el sustantivo "mapamundi" fue lo que se hizo masculino, tal vez porque "mundus" era masculino, y de ahí la palabra se acortó a "mapa" pero manteniéndose en masculino.

Comment: @Diego mi pregunta iba más del lado histórico y etimológico, no de concordancia. Ahora edito la pregunta para ser más claro. Hice uso del ejemplo del águila porque es forma parte de una regla en español bastante clara, pero Mapa no entra dentro de ella.

Comment: @DanteLlaguno La reabro. Me sigue confundiendo lo de "¿Hay alguna razón por el cual el género de esta palabra es femenino?", ya que águila y agua sí son nombres femeninos, pero mapa es masculino. En cualquier caso, dado el comentario de guifa se entiende la pregunta.

Comment: @R0tten GRacias por la observación. Razón tienes, pero después de cerrar y reabrir, voy a dejar que sea la comunidad la que use los votos y las colas de revisión (y los _edits_) para mejorar, cerrar, mantener abierta,etc. la pregunta. Estoy abusando un poco de mis privilegios de moderador y no debería ser el único en tener algo que decir. No sé si el comentario de Charlie es la respuesta buscada o si el OP pregunta otra cosa. Que se pronuncie el OP y que la comunidad le eche un cable.

Comment: Una aclaración: la "A" tónica no cambia el género del sustantivo "agua", lo que cambia es el género del artículo determinado "el".

Comment: @vitton es que todo sustantivo que es femenino pero que comienza por el sonido "a", debe llevar el artículo "el", como "el agua", "el hacha", "el arma", etc.

Comment: "mapa" es una excepción, así  cómo hay otras excepciones similares. En Chile, al bus de transporte público se le llama "la micro". Yo tenía una amiga española que insistía en llamarle "el micro". :-)

Comment: Estoy confundido ~ según WR, es el micro ... https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=micro

Answer (score 6):

De hecho, la palabra *mapa* ha tenido un género ambiguo hasta la edición de 1837 del diccionario de la RAE, en la que aparece por primera vez como de género masculino. La explicación es simplemente que proviene del latín *mappa*, que era femenino. Dice Covarrubias en su diccionario de 1611:

> MAPA [...] puede venir de mappa, que quiere dezir lienço, o toalla, y particularmente la que los Pretores en los juegos Circenses embiavan por señal, para que se empeçassen [...].

De hecho la voz latina *mappa* [se traduce](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=mappa&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) como "servilleta, toalla". Estos trapos o lienzos fueron los que se usaron para confeccionar los primeros mapas, y por eso se llamaron *mappa mundi*: el paño donde está dibujado el mundo.

Durante mucho tiempo se ha usado la voz *mapa* tanto en masculino como femenino, debido su origen como sustantivo latino femenino, pero también por influencia de *mundi* que es masculino:

> *Aqui comiença la mapa del mundo dela partida de orient que es dita asia de europa e de sus encontradas de africa.*
>
> Anónimo, "Libro del Tesoro. Girona, Catedral 20a5", 1400-1425 (España).
>
> *De las quales mis obras que yo he fecho la primera es la Redubción moral [...], la quarta El mapa mundi e la discripción della; [...].*
>
> Pero López de Ayala, "Traducción de las Décadas de Tito Luvio", c1400 (España).

El propio *Diccionario de Autoridades* de la RAE, en su tomo G-M de 1734, dice:

> MAPA. s. amb. La descripción geográphica de la tierra, que regularmente se hace en papel ò lienzo, en que se ponen los lugares, mares, rios, montañas, y otras cosas notables, con las distancias proporcionadas [...].

Nótese el "s. amb." que significa "sustantivo ambiguo". Y cita como ejemplos de la ambigüedad:

> *Por esta causa los Cosmógraphos hacen una* mapa, *en que se pintan todas las principales partes y naciones del mundo.*
>
> *Quando un Cosmógrapho saca un* mapa *general de España, ó de todo el mundo, pone alli las principales cosas dél.*

Estos ejemplos muestran que en el siglo XVI aún se mantenía la ambigüedad. Sin embargo, a partir del siglo XVII ya se nota el declive de la versión femenina: la búsqueda en este siglo de términos como "la mapa" o "una mapa" en el CORDE arroja simplemente un par de resultados, mientras que "el mapa" o "un mapa" arroja más de 50. Los resultados más recientes de *mapa* en femenino hacen alusión a su tercera acepción como "lo que sobresale de un género":

> *—Compañeros, antes que la corte de las Españas y la mapa del mundo, que es Madrid, caiga en poder de los gabachones, tuertos, botelludos, dejémonos matar tras esas piedras.*
>
> Benito Pérez Galdós, "Napoleón en Chamartín", 1874 (España).

Resulta curiosa esta acepción, que ha mantenido la versión femenina del sustantivo *mapa* cambiando sutilmente la definición de esta como "plano que guía al viajero" a "aquello que destaca y por tanto debe guiar a lo demás".

Os dejo con una cita de este último autor:

> *—Me han dicho que la gente de Cádiz, los políticos y los periodistas se ríen de mí —dijo D. Juan Martín frunciendo el ceño—, porque una vez dije la mapa en vez de el mapa. Los militares no estamos obligados a estar siempre con el libro en la mano, viendo cómo se dicen y cómo no se dicen las cosas. Yo sé mi obligación, que es perseguir a los franceses. Lo demás no me importa.*
>
> Benito Pérez Galdós, "Juan Martín el Empecinado", 1874 (España).

---

Curiosidad final. El significado original de *mappa* nos ha llegado (aunque tal vez no del todo intacto) al idioma español como *mopa*: Latín *mappa*, valón *mappe*, que pasó al inglés antiguo, actualizado como *[mop](https://www.etymonline.com/word/mop#etymonline_v_18343)* y de ahí *[mopa](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PlQHDM9)*. En este caso sí se ha mantenido el género femenino de la palabra.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás el cambio de femenino a masculino se vio influido por que casi siempre iba seguido de mundi, que suena masculino. Mapa mundi o mapamundi, el mapa del mundo.
Un caso similar a la palabra 'moto', que es femenina porque es una abreviatura de motocicleta.